# How to consume CDC changes from a Oracle Database Table in two different Talend projects?

Tags: talend, oracle-cdc

I want consume CDC changes from a Oracle Database table in two different Talend projects.
Does "Talend CDC" support such a requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The CDC db stores a record of the changes on monitored tables.  You need to create a job to read those changes and update the master (target) db.  If you want to consume from 2 different projects then that is the same as saying you want to consumer from 2 different jobs.  The key to this is to make sure the change data is still available after the first job runs.  For the `tOracleCDC` component in the first job, under advanced settings check off "Keep data in CDC table". Then the change data is still available for the second job.  Make sure you second job does not have this checked off otherwise you will keep processing the same data.

[image]

Not sure if you also need the CDC metadata to show up in both projects, but if you do there are 2 ways.  a. setup your CDC using a reference project and make that available to both projects.  b. setup your cdc metadata in one project. Talend will create and execute the underlying sql scripts and show the results in the metadata. repeat steps in second project.  You will get errors running the same sql scripts from the second project, but Talend will then recognize the cdc database and monitored tables in both projects (in other words the metadata will look the same in both projects showing the CDC).